# Getting error importing opencsv package

Tags: java, opencsv

I am trying to use opencsv to manipulate csv files in java

I am using BlueJ as my IDE

When I compile the code I get the following error

package au.com.bytecode.opencsv does not exist.

I also tried to compile using javac in command prompt in windows 7 but I get the same error.

I havetried surfing the web and alt of people have the same problem biy no one has given the solution to the problem.

Here is my code

```
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.Arrays;

import au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVReader;

public class TubeBlue1
{
   @SuppressWarnings("resource")
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
   {
      //Build reader instance
      //Read data.csv
      //Default seperator is comma
      //Default quote character is double quote
      //Start reading from line number 2 (line numbers start from zero)
      CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("data.csv"), ',' , '"' , 1);

      //Read CSV line by line and use the string array as you want
      String[] nextLine;
      while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
         if (nextLine != null) {
            //Verifying the read data here
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(nextLine));
         }
       }
   }
}
```

Please help me fix this problem.

Thanks

Vishal Ved

Answer (score 1):

is the opencsv library in your classpath?  that error says that the jvm compiler cannot find the class, so it is a good bet you don't have the library in the classpath for javac to find.